# No se renderizan los estilos de Tailwindcss añadidos mediante templates strings

Tags: javascript, dom, tailwind

Tengo el siguiente componente de un botón; estoy utilizando tailwindcss para darle estilos, pero pasa algo y es que el valor de `options.bg` que lo añado utilizando las template strings no se renderiza una vez en el DOM, aunque en el inspector de elementos la clase sí se muestra añadida correctamente.

```
export class Button {
    constructor(options = { content, bg }) {
        const btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.textContent = options.content;
        btn.className = `rounded border border-${options.bg} px-2 py-1 text-${options.bg} transition duration-300 hover:bg-${options.bg} hover:text-white`;
        return btn;
    }
}
```

Aquí creo la instancia el botón:

```
import { Button } from "./components/Button.js";

export default function App() {
    const main = document.getElementById("app");
    const DecreaseBtn = new Button({ content: "Decrease", bg: "blue-500" });

    main.innerHTML = `<h1 class="text-center text-4xl font-semibold">Counter</h1>`;
    main.appendChild(DecreaseBtn);
}
```

Este es el archivo de configuración de tailwind (cabe recalcar que instalé el CLI):

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["./public/**/*.{html,js}", "./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [require("prettier-plugin-tailwindcss")],
};
```

Al final el resultado es el botón que se añade correctamente, pero sin que las clases de `border-${options.bg} text-${options.bg} text-${options.bg}` aunque estas sí se ven en el inspector de elementos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que se tiene es que, como lo especifica la documentación:

> *Tailwind no incluye ninguna forma de tiempo de ejecución del lado del cliente, por lo que los nombres de las clases deben ser extraíbles estáticamente en tiempo de compilación y no pueden depender de ningún valor dinámico arbitrario que cambie en el cliente*.

[image: ejemplo clases dinámicas taiwind]

por lo que en este caso, se debe pasar como valor de `options.bg` el className de tailwind completo, o bien pasarlo de forma estática